# Docker Build : The "ContainerBuildAndLaunch" task failed unexpectedly. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Win32.Registry

Tags: c#, linux, docker, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to build my .Net 6.0 API Project in Visual studio 2022, and I get the following error.

```
MSB4018 The "ContainerBuildAndLaunch" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Win32.Registry, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'  user declined directory sharing
```

Even though project target OS Framework - Linux, it is looking out for `Microsoft.Win32.Registry` for some reason. Any direction will be highly appreciated.

Docker file

#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["BPBComputerGadgets.ProductsAPI/BPBComputerGadgets.ProductsAPI.csproj", "BPBComputerGadgets.ProductsAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "BPBComputerGadgets.ProductsAPI/BPBComputerGadgets.ProductsAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/BPBComputerGadgets.ProductsAPI"
RUN dotnet build "BPBComputerGadgets.ProductsAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "BPBComputerGadgets.ProductsAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BPBComputerGadgets.ProductsAPI.dll"]
```

Comment: Can you show the docker file as well? It could be that the base image has a defect, as a workaround you could add a nuget package reference to your projects for Microsoft.Win32.Registry then it should build at least

Comment: added the docker file in the question

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have latest version of docker Installed

The issue was the  `user declined directory sharing`. Opened the docker desktop->settings->Resources->File Sharing and Add the folders -> Apply and restart.

[image]

Comment: I tried this and I still get the same error.

Comment: what folder your file is present in?

Comment: I installed newer version of docker desktop and did resource file sharing as you mentioned above and that resolved it. Thank you!